# Laravel: how to change the data of all models?

Tags: laravel

Currently the system has a few dozen models, controllers and a few hundred routes.

When carrying out any query in the database, if a certain value is found during that query, I can transform this data into another value.

An example to facilitate understanding is, when performing the query and before presenting the result, a hashtag is found, that hashtag is replaced with another value.

In this example, the difficulty is not to change the value itself (`str_replace()`), but to be able to intercept any of the results of queries to the database, search for this "keyword" and replace it.

But this change is only visual, it is not replacing the data in the database.

Of course I can do this on each controller, but due to the quantity, I don't think anything is viable

I think I need to somehow be able to intercept all the results of any consultation with the database and make this substitution, but I have no idea if I should use `Middleware` or another Laravel resource, or even that should be done by a `ServiceProvider`.

Comment: Can't you use an accessor? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor This helps in replacing keys whenever the model is serialised into an array. Optionally you could also overwrite the `toArray` function, or define resources for each model which you return from the controller functions.

Comment: Is an alternative, but there are a few dozen models, and there are also some to query directly in the database (`\DB::query()`). I believe it is not feasible to modify so many classes. Not to mention that it still wouldn't solve everything, because I have these queries directly in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Laravel's [Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections).

You could create a `HashtagResource` and run all model results through it prior to utilising the data which could then look for the hashtag and replace it within the content as described.

For example, inside of the newly generated resource that wraps around your query, ie `HashtagResource::collection(MyModel::all())`

```php
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'content' => str_replace('#hashtag','#otherhashtag', $this->content)
        ];
    }
```